# What does the condition "if (n/10)" with integral n specify?

Tags: c

I am looking at the following piece of code:

```
void printd(int n)
{
     if (n < 0) {
         putchar('-');
         n = -n;
     }
     if (n / 10)
         printd(n / 10);
     putchar(n % 10 + '0');
}
```

I understand the first if statement fine, but the second one has me confused on a couple of points.

By itself, since "n" is an integer, I understand that n/10 will shift the decimal point to the left once - effectively removing the last digit of the number; however, I am having a little trouble understanding how this can be a condition by itself without the result being equal to something. Why isn't the condition if ((n/10) >= 0) or something?

Also, why is the '0' passed into the putchar() call?

Can someone tell me how it would read if you were to read it aloud in English?

Thanks!

Comment: In an if statement condition, zero := false, anything else is true...

Comment: ah ok, so it divides n by 10 each time until the result is 0; executing the code while it does not equal zero.

Comment: Also, indentation is misleading in second `if`. `putchar` is not in it.

Comment: Each time? No looping here. You didn't post the real code I guess.

Comment: FWIW this is a diabolical way to test n>=10 as can be witnessed by the fact you had to ask this question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan each time printd() calls itself

Comment: Eek, recursion too! Printing an int shouldn't be so complex. Does your system not have printf?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan hehe I don't plan on using it for anything, it was just an example that I was trying to understand :D

Comment: Your question is captured by "Why isn't the
condition if ((n/10) >= 0) or something?" The answer is that the code should be >= and the author of the code in the Q was mis-guided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `n / 10` will evaluate to false if the result is 0, true otherwise. Essentially it's checking if `n > 10 && n < -10` (the -10 doesn't come into play here due to the `n = -n` code)

The `+ '0'` is for character offset, as characters '0'-'9' are not represented by numbers 0-9, but rather at an offset (48-57 with ascii).

> Can someone tell me how it would read if you were to read it aloud in English?

If you're talking about the conditional, then I would say "if integer n divided by 10 is not zero"

Comment: The only time it is checking for `n < -10` is if `n` was `INT_MIN` on entry to the function (and the machine uses 2's complement arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

`n/10` will not shift the decimal number since `n` is an integer. The division will produce the result like this: if n = 25, then `n/10` would be 2 (without any decimal points), similarly if n = 9, then n/10 would be 0 in which case `if` condition would not be satisfied.

Regarding the `+'0'`, since  n%10 produces an integer result and in `putchar` you are printing a `char` , you need to convert the integer to a char. This is done by adding the ascii value of 0 to the integer.

Answer (score 0):

In C, there is no separate boolean type; an expression like `a > b` evaluates to zero if false, non-zero if true. Sometimes you can take advantage of this when testing for zero or non-zero in an int.

As for the `'0'`, that just performs character arithmetic so that the right character is printed. The zero character has an ASCII encoding value which isn't zero, so the `n` value is used as an offset from that encoding to get the right numeric digit printed out.

Comment: Sometime, you need to read the C99 (or C11) standard to find out about `_Bool` and `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: And it is **guaranteed** that `a > b` evaluates to 0 or 1 (and not some other non-zero value). It's just that in **conditions** the non-zero value of an expression is treated as *true*.

Comment: @Jens: I never claimed that `a > b` would evaluate to anything other than 0 or 1. All I said was that it is non-zero if true, *which is true since 1 is not 0*.